# How does orElse work on PartialFunctions

Tags: scala, functional-programming, read-eval-print-loop, partialfunction

I am getting very bizarre behavior (at least it seems to me) with the `orElse` method defined on `PartialFunction`

It would seem to me that:

```
val a = PartialFunction[String, Unit] {
    case "hello" => println("Bye")
}
val b: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = a.orElse(PartialFunction.empty[Any, Unit])
a("hello") // "Bye"
a("bogus") // MatchError
b("bogus") // Nothing
b(true)    // Nothing
```

makes sense but this is not how it is behaving and I am having a lot of trouble understanding why as the types signatures seem to indicate what I exposed above.

Here is a transcript of what I am observing with Scala 2.11.2:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val a = PartialFunction[String, Unit] {
     | case "hello" => println("Bye")
     | }
a: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

scala> a("hello")
Bye

scala> a("bye")
scala.MatchError: bye (of class java.lang.String)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:242)
  at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
  ... 33 elided

scala> val b = a.orElse(PartialFunction.empty[Any, Unit])
b: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

scala> b("sdf")
scala.MatchError: sdf (of class java.lang.String)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:242)
  at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:162)
  ... 33 elided
```

Note the return type of `val b` which has not widen the type of the PartialFunction.

But this also does not work as expected:

```
scala> val c = a.orElse(PartialFunction.empty[String, Unit])
c: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

scala> c("sdfsdf")
scala.MatchError: sdfsdf (of class java.lang.String)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:242)
  at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:162)
  ... 33 elided
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your attempt, but first let's see a working implementation:

```
scala> val a: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = { case "hello" => println("bye") }
a: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val b: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = { case _ => println("fallback") }
b: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val c = a.orElse(b)
c: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

scala> c("hello")
bye

scala> c("foo")
fallback
```

There's two main errors in your code:

1. the way the PF is defined
2. the (wrong) assumption that `empty` is a "catch-all" function that returns `Nothing`

#### 1. How to define a PartialFunction

```
val right: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
  case "hello" => println("bye")
}
```

How **not** to define it:

```
val wrong = PartialFunction[String, Unit] {
  case "hello" => println("bye")
}
```

If you look at the definition of `PartialFunction.apply`

```
def apply[A, B](f: A => B): PartialFunction[A, B] = { case x => f(x) }
```

you'll see that it defines a partial function for *any* `x` and it applies the given `f` function to it. Now your `{ case "hello" => println("bye") }` is the `f` argument, so you approximately end up with the following (clearly unexpected) `PartialFunction`:

```
val wrong: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
  case x => x match {
    case "hello" => println("bye")  
  }
```

So when you ask whether it's defined it will always return true, since it's defined for **any** string:

```
wrong.isDefinedAt("hello") // true (ok)
wrong.isDefinedAt("whatever") // true (sure?)
```

but when you try to `apply` it

```
wrong("hello") // bye (ok)
wrong("whatever") // MatchError (BOOM!)
```

you fall short on the **inner** match.

Since `orElse` decides whether to call the "else" depending on the result of `isDefined`, then it's obvious why it fails.

#### 2. Empty catches nothing!

Straight from the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction$):

> `def empty[A, B]: PartialFunction[A, B]`
>
> The partial function with empty domain. Any attempt to invoke empty partial function leads to throwing `scala.MatchError` exception.

The `PartialFunction` (well, it's not really partial anymore) you're looking for is:

```
val fallback: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = { case _ => println("fallback") }
```

or - just to show that we learn from our mistakes -

```
val fallback = PartialFunction[Any, Unit] { _ => println("fallback") }
```

Comment: Why is the type of `c` `PartialFunction[String, Unit]` instead of `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`?

Comment: @UndercoverAgent, if you look at the definition of `orElse` it should actually reject `b` as a parameter, since `Any` is not a subtype of `String`. It somehow treats `b` as `PartialFunction[String, Unit]` and makes it work. Anyway the type returned by `orElse` will never be wider than the original functions composed.

Comment: @UndercoverAgent, I've been reasoning about this for a while and I must say that I'm baffled. `orElse` should definitely reject `b`. I asked a question, let's see whether someone can figure this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394557/is-partialfunction-orelse-looser-on-its-type-bounds-that-it-should-be

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `PartialFunction` object apply method which is defined so:

```
def apply[A, B](f: A => B): PartialFunction[A, B] = { case x => f(x) }
```

Basically it takes a function form `A` to `B` and automatically wrap it in a case statement, the problem is that you are passing the case too and I'm not 100% sure of what happens then, you can try passing a function to the apply or easily you can try without using the apply method:

```
scala>   val a: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
     |     case "hello" => println("Bye")
     |   }
a: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

scala>   val b: PartialFunction[String, Unit] =  {
     |     case _ => println("default")
     |   }
b: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>

scala> b("123")
default
```

You could also extend the trait and implement `apply` and `isDefined` as shown [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html).

Comment: You're right in saying the the issue is with the apply method. You get a partial function defined on any x, on which the given function is then applied. See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`PartialFunction.empty[A,B]` is equivalent to:

```
{
  case x: Nothing => x
}
```

(This typechecks, because `Nothing` is a subtype of both `A` and `B`.)

or, equivalently:

```
{
  // note: this is probably not a valid Scala code for a partial function
  // but, as PartialFunction.empty's name suggests, it's an *empty* block
}
```

This cannot match anything.

`.orElse` can be understood to simply concatenates lists of case statements from two `PartialFunction`s. So, in your case `a.orElse(PartialFunction.empty[Any,Unit]` means:

```
{ case "hello" => println("Bye") } orElse { /* no cases here */ }
```

which simplifies to:

```
{ case "hello" => println("Bye") }
```

or

```
{ case "hello" => println("Bye"); case x:Nothing => x }
```

`MatchError` is therefore obvious.

Note that [the documetation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction$) also mentions that `empty` always throws `MatchError`.

---

From what I can guess, you wanted a `PartialFunction` that always matches. There's no named method in the standard library for that, but why should there be. You can simply write

```
{ case _ => () }
```

Comment: If I define `val b: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = a.orElse(PartialFunction[String, Unit] { case _ => println("123") })`, I still get match exception if I do `b("123")`, anyway I think you are right that `PartialFunction.empty` matches `Nothing`.

Comment: @EndeNeu, you're right, there's two errors. This answer catches the second one, but the `MatchError` happens before

Comment: @GabrielePetronella if I define `b` as stated in my comment there's no match on `Nothing` because I'm not using `PartialFunction.empty` anymore, I have two separate PF, one that matches `"hello"` and the other that matches `_`.

Comment: @EndeNeu as I explain in my answer, `a` is ill-defined and that's where the issue occurs.