# Is PartialFunction orElse looser on its type bounds than it should be?

Tags: scala, types, partialfunction

Let's define a `PartialFunction[String, String]` and a `PartialFunction[Any, String]`

Now, given the definition of `orElse`

```
def orElse[A1 <: A, B1 >: B](that: PartialFunction[A1, B1]): PartialFunction[A1, B1]
```

I would expect not to be able to compose the the two, since

`A` → `String`
`A1` → `Any`

and therefore the bound `A1 <: A` (i.e. `Any <: String`) doesn't hold.

Unexpectedly, I can compose them and obtain a `PartialFunction[String, String]` defined on the whole `String` domain. Here's an example:

```
val a: PartialFunction[String, String] = { case "someString" => "some other string" }
// a: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

val b: PartialFunction[Any, String] = { case _ => "default" }
// b: PartialFunction[Any,String] = <function1>

val c = a orElse b
// c: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

c("someString")
// res4: String = some other string

c("foo")
// res5: String = default

c(42)
// error: type mismatch;
//   found   : Int(42)
//   required: String
```

Moreover, if I explicitly provide the `orElse` type parameters

```
a orElse[Any, String] b
// error: type arguments [Any,String] do not conform to method orElse's type parameter bounds [A1 <: String,B1 >: String]
```

the compiler finally shows some sense.

Is there any type system sorcery I'm missing that causes `b` to be a valid argument for `orElse`? In other words, how come that `A1` is inferred as `String`?

If the compiler infers `A1` from `b` then it must be `Any`, so where else does the inference chain that leads to `String` start?

---

## Update

After playing with the REPL I noticed that `orElse` returns an intersection type `A with A1` when the types don't match. Example:

```
val a: PartialFunction[String, String] = { case "someString" => "some other string" }
// a: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

val b: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = { case 42 => 32 }
// b: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = <function1>

a orElse b
// res0: PartialFunction[String with Int, Any] = <function1>
```

Since `(String with Int) <:< String` this works, even though the resulting function is practically unusable. I also suspect that `String with Any` is unified into `Any`, given that

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
// import reflect.runtime.universe._   

typeOf[String] <:< typeOf[String with Any]
// res1: Boolean = true

typeOf[String with Any] <:< typeOf[String]
// res2: Boolean = true
```

So that's why mixing `String` and `Any` results into `String`.

That being said, what is going on under the hood? Under which logic are the mismatching types unified?

## Update 2

I've reduced the issue to a more general form:

```
class Foo[-A] {
  def foo[B <: A](f: Foo[B]): Foo[B] = f
}

val a = new Foo[Any]
val b = new Foo[String]

a.foo(b) // Foo[String] Ok, String <:< Any
b.foo(a) // Foo[String] Shouldn't compile! Any <:!< String
b.foo[Any](a) // error: type arguments [Any] do not conform to method foo's type parameter bounds [A <: String]
```

Comment: Pretty sure the compiler is just inferring the strictest return type it can find.

Comment: and than inferring the other types backward?

Comment: Nitpick: "String with Int" is not a union type as - by definition - being one would require both "String" and "Int" to fulfill the interface of "String with Int" independently, which is not the case. "String" is not <: "String with Int" and "Int" is not <: "String with Int".

Comment: thanks @Utaal, it's indeed an intersection rather than a union. Fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this upside down.

You can always pass to a method requiring a parameter of type `A` any argument of type `B <: A`, i.e. any subtype of `A`. That is if you have

```
def foo(a: Animal)
```

you can pass a `Dog` to `foo`, because `Dog <: Animal`.

In the same way, if you have

```
def foo(l: List[Animal])
```

you can pass a `List[Dog]` to it, because `List` is covariant with its type parameter and since `Dog <: Animal`, then `List[Dog] <: List[Animal]`

Now if you have

```
def foo(pf: PartialFunction[String, String])
```

you can pass a `PartialFunction[Any, String]`, because `PartialFunction` is contravariant with the first type parameter and covariant with the second. Since `Any >: String`, then `PartialFuncion[Any, String] <: PartialFunction[String, String]`.

Now, for the type bounds, the compiler will try to infer `A1` and `B1`, such that

- `A1` is subtype of `A`
- `B2` is subtype of `B`

To do so, it will look for:

- the greatest common subtype of `Any` and `String`, since `A` and `A1` are in contravariant position
- the least common supertype of `String` and `String`, since `B` and `B1` is covariant position

Results

- `A1` → `String`
- `B1` → `String`

---

The case in which you compose a `PartialFunction[String, String`] with a `PartialFunction[Int, Int]` is an odd-looking case of the previous example, in which:

- the greatest common subtype of `String` and `Int` is `String with Int`, i.e. the interesection of the two types, which is subtype of both (in this case is pretty much as saying `Nothing`: being *both* a `String` and an `Int` doesn't seem very likely)
- the least common supertype of `String` and `Int` is `Any`

therefore

```
val a: PartialFunction[String, String] = ...
val b: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = ...
a orElse b // PartialFunction[String with Int, Any] // as expected, although not very useful...
```

Comment: "You're getting this upside down." Are you answering yourself in the second person? :D. Regardless that seems to give a good overview of what is happening.

Comment: Nice answer! Much more complete than mind, though I don't find it absolutely necessary to re-explain covariance and contra-variance here, interested parties can look that up at other places.

Comment: Still don't fully understand the String with Int part though. Maybe I just haven't spent enough time thinking about it, but if you truly want to make your answer comprehensive, you might want to elaborate a bit on this.

Comment: @UndercoverAgent Imagine this: `class A extends B with C`. Then the following are all true for `val a = new A`. `a.isInstanceOf[B]`, `a.isInstanceOf[C]` and `a.isInstanceOf[B with C]`. You use the `with` all the time with inheritance. It combines types with an `and`. It is B and C at the same time.

Comment: @Kigyo, precisely, that's me answering my naive question, in SO style!

About explaining contravariance, well I was explaining it to the OP, which apparently forgot what it is :P

Answer (score 4):

I was going to say that `PartialFunction[Any, String]` is a subtype of `PartialFunction[String, String]` because of contra-variance if I understand correctly. This would explain the behavior described in your question before the update, but you got me all mixed up with this union type stuff.

I don't even know what the hell `String with Int` means!

Comment: It's not a matter of contra-variance, the type bound is very specific: `A1` (i.e. `Any`) must be a subtype of `A` (i.e. `Any`), which is false. Variance is irrelevant here.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella A1 <: A, or String <: String. PF[Any, String] <: PF[String, String].

Comment: I removed my downvote, since I was wrong. However this answer would definitely need some elaboration.

Comment: It's a _subtype_ but not a _subclass_.

Answer (score 1):

This is of course vague and only my humble opinion. Suggestions and comments are appreciated.

Taking from this SO question. ([How to know if an object is an instance of a TypeTag's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628379/how-to-know-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-typetags-type))

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
implicit class MyInstanceOf[U: TypeTag](that: U) {
  def myIsInstanceOf[T: TypeTag] = 
    typeOf[U] <:< typeOf[T]
}
```

We have a proper way to check `isInstanceOf` without erasure.

```
val b: PartialFunction[Any, String] = { case _ => "default" }
b.myIsInstanceOf[PartialFunction[String, String]] //true
```

And it only makes sense. If you have a function from `Any => String`, then it accepts any input. So it also accepts `String` input. That's why it can also be treated as a Function from `String => String`. Basically it can be treated as `T => String` for any `T`.

So in the end the compiler agrees on `A -> String` and `A1 -> String`.

```
 a.orElse[String,String](b) //works
```

Edit: Final thoughts

You should not think of `A1 <: A` as a restriction. It will only infer the type of the resulting `PartialFunction`.
There is no way that `orElse` cannot be applied. Both PF involved are contra-variant on `A` and therefore a common subtype for BOTH can always be found that satisfies `A1 <: A`.

I think an analogy would be addition of fractions, where you think, oh, they have not a common denominator and therefore can not be added. Both fractions can be adjusted (or: seen differently) to have a common denominator. The compiler although wants to find the smallest common denominator and not resort to the easy way with multiplying with the other denominator. (`A with A'`)

For the other type `B` it's the same. Both are co-variant and therefore a common super type can also always be found. `Any` in the worst case.

Comment: From a general standpoint, I agree with the compiler as well. However I don't get what's the inference rule being followed here. The static type of `b` is `PartialFunction[Any, String]` and this is incompatible with `PartialFunction[String, String]`, unless you decide to downcast `Any` to `String`. Why is the compiler doing it? Where does the hint come from?

Comment: Yeah, this comment is wrong. It's very compatible, or conforming.

Comment: The two `PartialFunction` are subtypes, but `Any` is definitely not a subtype of `String`. Also `Int` is not a subtype of `String` but `orElse` works for `PF[Int, String]` and `PF[String, String]`.

Comment: Thank you, your last edit seems quite legit. I still need to process all the information (and I might even try to write down an answer myself) but your input was very helpful.

Comment: I personally also didn't look much into this kind of stuff. I partially rely on my common sense here. Would appreciate a more detailed answer with more knowledge and facts rather than instinct.

Comment: `You should not think of A1 <: A as a restriction.` Maybe you mean that the function domains are augmented, see the docs. But type args set expected types for value args, so what you choose matters. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction@orElse[A1%3C:A,B1%3E:B](that:PartialFunction[A1,B1]):PartialFunction[A1,B1]

Comment: Yea, maybe bad wording. I just wanted to express that one should not have to worry about `orElse` not being applicable. (If you don't specify the types manually)

Answer (score 1):

You already typed this in, but:

```
scala> val a: PartialFunction[String, String] = { case "a" => "b" }
a: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

scala> val b: PartialFunction[Any, String] = { case 1 => "one" }
b: PartialFunction[Any,String] = <function1>

scala> a orElse b
res0: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

scala> a orElse[String,String] b
res1: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

scala> a orElse[Any,String] b
<console>:10: error: type arguments [Any,String] do not conform to method orElse's type parameter bounds [A1 <: String,B1 >: String]
              a orElse[Any,String] b
              ^

scala> import reflect.runtime._ ; import universe._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

scala> typeOf[PartialFunction[Any,String]] <:< typeOf[PartialFunction[String,String]]
res3: Boolean = true
```

Because of the contravariant type param, you can use PF[Any, String] here.

To answer the question, where does it say what it will pick?

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#local-type-inference

E.g., it promises to infer a maximal A1 in contravariant position, but still conforming to the constraint <: A.

Comment: I get the contravariance point, but still `Any` is not a subtype of `String`, so how can the `A1 <:< A` bound respected?

Comment: I commented on the other answer. A1 and A are both String.

Comment: I mean, clearly it's because the inferred type parameter for `A1` is `String` and not `Any`, but why such inference occur?

Comment: Because it works?  Sorry, I'm running out for school pick-up. You showed it doesn't work with A1 as Any.

Comment: I miss the precise rule for which `Any` gets statically inferred as `String`. I'm convinced the explanation is right, but I still miss that bit.

Comment: Not Any, just A1. Try `a orElse[Nothing, String] b`. The types are OK, just not useful.

Comment: also `typeOf[PartialFunction[Int,String]] <:< typeOf[PartialFunction[String,String]]` is `false`, but you can still compose them

Comment: If you infer `A1` from the type of `b`, then you must infer `Any`. The question is: where does the inference chain that leads `A1` to be `String` start from?

Comment: Well I guess it's like that: We initially have `String` - `Int` and both are contra-variant. So when two types are contra-variant, we can deduce a common subtype that is a subtype of both. The last resort would be to mix the types like `String with Int`.

Comment: that would also explain why the resulting function return type is `Any`, which is the least common supertype for the two covariant types. I need to reason about this, but I think you finally convinced me.